# Unity3D playing sound when Player collides with an object with a specific tag

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, audio

I using Unity 2019.2.14f1 to create a simple 3D game.

In that game, I want to play a sound anytime my Player collides with a gameObject with a specific tag.

The MainCamera has an Audio Listener and I am using Cinemachine Free Look, that is following my avatar, inside the ThridPersonController (I am using the one that comes on [Standard Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351) - but I have hidden Ethan and added my own character/avatar).

The gameObject with the tag that I want to destroy have an Audio Source:

[image: Audio Source on the GameObject with the specific tag]

---

In order to make the sound playing on the collision, I started by creating an empty gameObject to serve as the AudioManager, and added a new component (C# script) to it:

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sound[] sounds;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;

            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Play (string name)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        s.source.Play();
    }
}
```

And created the script Sound.cs:

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound
{
    public string name;

    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume;
    [Range(.1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch;

    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioSource source;
}
```

After that, in the Unity UI, I went to the Inspector in the gameObject AudioManager, and added a new element in the script that I named: CatchingPresent.

[image: AudioManager - Sound that I want to play when the player collides with an object.]

On the Third Person Character script, in order to destroy a gameObject (with a specific tag) when colliding with it, I have added the following:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                count = count - 1;
                SetCountText();

            }
        }
```

It is working properly as that specific object is disappearing on collision. Now, in order to play the sound "CatchingPresent" anytime the Player collides with the object with the tag, in this case, `Present`, I have tried adding the following to the `if` in the `OnCollisionEnter`:

- `FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("CatchingPresent");`

But I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'AudioManager' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

- `AudioManager.instance.Play("CatchingPresent");`

But I get the error:

> The name 'AudioManager' does not exist in the current context

As all the compiler errors need to be fixed before entering the Playmode, any guidance on how to make the sound playing after a collision between the player and the gameObject with the tag `Present` is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformulated the approach that I was following and solved the problem by simply adding an Audio Source to the ThirdPersonController (with the AudioClip that I wanted to call) and added `GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();` to the if statement as it follows:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                count = count - 1;
                SetCountText();
                GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solution is working fine with just one Audio Source, however I am not sure how it would be with 2 or more.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since the Standard assets for the character are in their own namespace it cant find your AudioManager code. Add the AudioManager to a namespace and then #include it in the character class.